# Batch edit "canvas" of photos with different aspect ratio

Tags: photo-editing, aspect-ratio

I have a batch of images that are of different size and aspect ratio.

I need to give them all a square canvas (x=y) with the image in the center.
With the imaging software that I am using (photoshop & GIMP), I can only find the option to set and center a batch of images in a fixed canvas. The problem with this is that the images that is to small for the canvas, gets a canvas that is too large, and the images that has an aspect (y, x or both) that is larger then the canvas will exceed the borders of the canvas.

Is it anyway to get a photo editing software to batch edit photos in to a square aspect ratio where the canvas size of each photo is determined by its largest aspect dimension? Meaning if a photo is 1400x600, the canvas for that image becomes 1400x1400 and a image that is 500x1000 becomes 1000x1000, with the image in center and the empty space generated by the new aspect in transparent or white.

I might be using the word "canvas" in a wrong way here. Think images with different aspect ratios and size -> Images with equal aspect ratios but different size.

Comment: command-line tool ImageMagick can do this fairly easily: `-extent 100x100%` and see https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=15123

Comment: I didn't manage to quickly achieve this solely with ImageMagic (which certainly is the tool for this) based on its docs ( https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent ) but this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39706261/2216968 looks like something that could help.

Comment: see also [Auto batch resize images through adding white space i.e. not distorting original proportions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102280/60903)

Comment: and [Batch resize images to a particular ratio without cropping](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88789/60903)

Answer (score 0):

To enlarge to square all images:

1. Copy this GIMP python-fu script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

def square_all_images(dummy_image, dummy_drawable):
    pdb.gimp_context_push()
    # Get the list of all opened images
    images = gimp.image_list()
    image_number = len(images)
    
    # Loop through each image
    for i in range(image_number):
        image = images[i]
        drawable = image.active_layer
        pdb.gimp_progress_update((i * 1.0) / image_number)
        pdb.gimp_progress_set_text("Processing image #" + str(i + 1) + " over " + str(image_number) + "...")

        # Get image size
        width = image.width
        height = image.height

        # Calculate the maximum dimension
        max_dim = max(width, height)

        # Calculate the new dimensions
        new_width = max_dim
        new_height = max_dim

        # Calculate the offset
        offset_x = (max_dim - width) // 2
        offset_y = (max_dim - height) // 2

        # Enlarge the canvas
        image.resize(new_width, new_height, offset_x, offset_y)
        drawable.resize(new_width, new_height, offset_x, offset_y)

        # Save the image file
        filename = pdb.gimp_image_get_filename(image)
        pdb.gimp_file_save(image, drawable, filename, '?')
    
    # Refresh the image to see the changes
    pdb.gimp_context_pop()
    pdb.gimp_displays_flush()

# Define the parameters for the script
register(
    "python_fu_square_all_images",
    "Curves on all images",
    "Curves on all images and save; identical values will be ignored",
    "Fabrice TIERCELIN",
    "Fabrice TIERCELIN",
    "2024",
    "<Image>/Filters/Enlarge to square all images",
    "*",
    [],
    [],
    square_all_images
)

# Main function
main()
```

2. Paste it into a text file
3. Save it with a `.py` extension
4. Put this file on your `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\plug-ins` folder (more information below if it doesn't work)
5. Start *GIMP*
6. Open all your image files by drag and drop
7. Go on *Filter* → *Enlarge to square all images*
8. Launch the script → all the files are already saved as square
9. Quit *GIMP* ignoring the prompts

For systems other than *Windows*, look at the settings in *GIMP*:

1. Click on *Edit*
2. Click on *Preferences*
3. Go on left pane; at bottom
4. Click on *Folders*
5. Click on *Plug-ins*
6. Click on *Add a new folder*

*Successfully tested on GIMP 2.10.36 on Windows 10.*